# How to override gradle.properties of a Cordova project from a plugin?

Tags: java, android, cordova, gradle, plugins

I'm developing a Cordova plugin for Android. It uses a couple of dependencies like:

`com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1`

`com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0`

So far it looks like (but please correct me if I'm wrong) they're imported properly if I add them to `plugin.xml`, which in turn inserts them into the project's `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
<framework src="com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1" />
<framework src="com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0" />
```

At least this isn't throwing a build error. I do get another error though:

```
This project uses AndroidX dependencies, but the 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled. Set this property to true in the gradle.properties file and retry.
```

And the problem is that a Cordova plugin has no `gradle.properties` file. The Cordova project has one, but changing `android.useAndroidX` and `android.enableJetifier` in it manually doesn't seem to help: the build will still throw the same error.

The question is: How can I tell Cordova to set these values in `gradle.properties` to `true`? Is there some way to update or overwrite `gradle.properties` at build time, in a similar way how the contents of `plugin.xml` are registered in `AndroidManifest.xml` and a gradle file attached to the plugin gets added to `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it doesn't need overriding. In the Cordova project's `config.xml` the following line should be added:

`<preference name="AndroidXEnabled" value="true" />`

Comment: that's not modifying grade.properties

Comment: Yes, that's not.

Comment: What I mean is, that line in config.xml does nothing for gradle.properties. It should but it's not!